# Bearded dragon skin condition

Tags: health, diseases, skin-condition, bearded-dragon

We have adopted a bearded dragon, over the last few months his skin has deteriorated at first we thought it was him shedding but his now nearly finished his shed and it seems to be worse than before. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: it is a fungal infection go to the vet right now.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve contacted a vet.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bad case of a fungal infection (yellow fungus potentially) to me. Read this article for more information: https://reptile.guide/yellow-fungus-bearded-dragons/

Most important thing you need to do is take him to a vet asap.